# C# access custom attributes of a partial class on MVC with EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

My situation is the following:
I'm coding a MVC website on Visual Studio 2013 using database-first approach with Entity Framework.

EF automatically generates the models. But I need to add custom attributes (~NOT~ necessarily for data validation but also for internal processes) and, via reflection, access those custom attributes.

Let's say I have

```
public partial class Application {
     public int AppID {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     //etc...
}
```

I've tried the following approaches:

• On a different file I continue the partial class:

```
public partial class Application {
    [MyAttributeOne]
    public int AppID { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [MyAttributeTwo]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

• Use the MetaData class

```
public class ApplicationMetadata {
    [MyAttributeOne]
    public int SolutionID { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [MyAttributeTwo]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(ApplicationMetadata))]
public partial class Application { }
```

• Inherit the class with attributes:

```
public class ApplicationMetadata {
    [MyAttributeOne]
    public int SolutionID { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [MyAttributeTwo]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Application : ApplicationMetadata { }
```

• And the 'Buddy class' approach where I do basically the previous 2 approaches but instead I define the class with the attributes inside the 'Application' class.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this simply impossible?

I need to be able to make the following code work:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in currentObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    foreach (CustomAttributeData attrData in propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributesData())
        {
            if (typeof(attrData) == typeof(MyAttributeOne))
                //stuff
            else if (typeof(attrData) == typeof(MyAttributeTwo))
                //different stuff
            else
                //yet more stuff
        }
}
```

Thank you very much for the attention!
Regards.

Comment: How about putting the metadata in a completely different class? In the same way as [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707339(v=vs.91).ASPX).

Comment: I've tried that, the second example is the metadata in a different class, or do you mean different _file_? Would that change anything?

Comment: I mean a completely different class, not one that the entity inherits from.

Comment: Can you illustrate that a little more? Would I use this different class in the code I need? How would I relate the DB info (using the auto-generated classes) and this new class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is a little involved but it's fairly simple. This is also really a bit of a brain dump but it does work and gives you enough to work with. Lets set up with some basics:

```
//A couple of custom attributes
public class MyAttributeOne : Attribute { }
public class MyAttributeTwo : Attribute { }

//A metadata class where we can use the custom attributes
public sealed class MyEntityMetadata
{
    //This property has the same name as the class it is referring to
    [MyAttributeOne]
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

//And an entity class where we use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MetadataType
//to tell our function where the metadata is stored
[MetadataType(typeof(MyEntityMetadata))]
public class MyEntity
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

OK, still with me? Now we need a function to process the properties in the same way you did earlier:

```
public void DoStuff(object currentObject)
{
    //Lets see if our entity class has associated metadata
    var metaDataAttribute = currentObject.GetType()
        .GetCustomAttributes()
        .SingleOrDefault(a => a is MetadataTypeAttribute) as MetadataTypeAttribute;

    PropertyInfo[] metaProperties = null;

    //Cache the metadata properties here
    if (metaDataAttribute != null)
    {
        metaProperties = metaDataAttribute.MetadataClassType.GetProperties();
    }

    //As before loop through each property...
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in currentObject.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        //Refactored this out as it's called again later
        ProcessAttributes(propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes());

        //Now check the metadata class
        if (metaProperties != null)
        {
            //Look for a matching property in the metadata class
            var metaPropertyInfo = metaProperties
                .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == propertyInfo.Name);

            if (metaPropertyInfo != null)
            {
                ProcessAttributes(metaPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And of course, here is the refactored method to process the attributes:

```
private void ProcessAttributes(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
{
    foreach (var attr in attributes)
    {
        if (attr is MyAttributeOne)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyAttributeOne found");
        }
        else if (attr is MyAttributeTwo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyAttributeTwo found");
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```